# Configuring org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient to use the default Authenticator

Tags: java, httpclient, authenticator

I am attempting to use DefaultHttpClient over a proxy with basic authentication. Setting the client to use the default ProxySelector is (sort of) straight forward:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.setRoutePlanner(new ProxySelectorRoutePlanner(
    client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry(),
    null));
```

However, this doesn't configure the client to use the default Authenticator. Is there a way to do this, or am I forced to setup the authentication explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom `CredentialsProvider` that delegates resolution of user credentials to the default Authenticator